# What RegExp can I use to obtain only the line that comes after another line?

Tags: regex, filtering, textmate

I need help with a regular expression filter.
I have a txt document with a list of descriptions that goes like this:

```
Job: Woodcutter

Wood, Herbs, Plants, Trees,

Beds, Chairs, Armor

Job: Mason

Dacite, Rock, Stone, Clay

Doors, Buldings

[...]
```

What I'm looking for is a RegExp that lets me filter through this document with TextMate and spits out:

```
Woodcutter
Wood, Herbs, Plants, Trees
Mason
Dacite, Rock, Stone, Clay
```

I've been trying to do it myself for the last 4 hours but I can't get it right. How would you do it?

Comment: I reformatted your post - I hope I got the line breaks right.

Comment: Every line break is a double line break in the original document. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

`/\n\w+:([^\n]*)\n+([^\n]*)\n/`

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work for me. What I get when using the "Filtering>Copy matching lines into a new document" bundle with TextMate is a blank document. Any ideas?

Comment: It could be because the regex I gave is for multiple lines. If TextMate is doing things one line at a time then it won't work, you may need to add some flags. I'm not sure what dialect TextMate uses.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a text editor suggestion, I suggest `sed`.

```
sed -n 's/Job: //;T;p;n;n;p' job.txt
```